# Associating items in a file python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

How could I call up two files or one file (I'm not too sure which would be easier) and associate two strings so that the program could tell if the user entered the correct counter string if one of them was output.
 So Line 'n' in file 1 would equal line n in file 2.

N.B.
I am creating a system (for a challenge: I'm quite new to Python) that checks whether a password is correct for the associated username and I was wondering whether I could use a file instead of a dictionary.
I HAVE looked around, but I couldn't find any questions which suited my purpose

Comment: A file is just a blob of data. If you wanted to access it like a dict, you'd have to read it into your program as a dict (or similar mapping structure) anyway.

Comment: Can you be more precise? You want line `n` in file 1 to be associated with line `n` in file 2? Or are you in general looking for data storage of a dictionary in a file? You could use a csv file, or a Python file with a dictionary inside then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are small files, read them both into lists line-by-line:

```
l1, l2 = [], [] # these will store the lines
for fname, l in [(fname1, l1), (fname2, l2)]: # read in one file at a time
    f = open(fname, "r") # opens in read mode
    for line in f:
        # line = line.strip() if you want to remove head/trailing newlines, tabs, etc
        l.append(line)
    f.close() # good practice to close explicitly even though GC would get it later
```

Now you can easily check for correspondence by accessing the lists:

```
is_match = (l2[i] == l2[i])
```

This will be more efficient than building a dictionary, if that matters to you.

P.S. Password systems should never store passwords in plain text. The common alternative is to store securely salted+hashed passwords. If you want to try this, it would require further reading on your part; see: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/